# Erro com a commons Mail "Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:465"

Tags: java, javamail

Olá.
Estou tentando fazer um envio de e-mail pelo java e estou usando a commons-mail e a javamail pra isso. Más está dando erro...
Segue método.
Já alterei o .."Permitir aplicativos menos seguros" no gmail

```
public void enviarEmail(String emailDeDestino, String assunto, String corpo)throws EmailException {

    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setAuthentication("rteste@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXXX");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom(emailDeDestino);
    email.setSubject(assunto);
    email.setMsg(corpo);
    email.addTo(emailDeDestino);
    email.send();
}
```